# Proofing the identity of double integrals over symmetric function

Tags: integration, multiple-integral, symmetry

In one of my physics classes we had given a double integral over a function $f$ in two variables:
$$G=\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x$$

The function $f$ is symmetric in its parameters:
$$f(x,y)=f(y,x)$$

We used this property to simplify the integral for later numerical integration:
$$\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x=2\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D, y\le x}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x$$

Although this makes intuitive sense to me, I was unable to prove it using the given equations alone. How can I properly prove that the equality given above is true?

**Attempt**

My idea for a proof so far was to do the following expansion:
$$\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x=\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D,y\le x}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x+\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D,y\ge x}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x$$

Renaming $x\rightarrow y'$ and $y\rightarrow x'$ in the second integral:
$$\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x=\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D,y\le x}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x+\int_{y'\in D}\int_{x'\in D,x'\ge y'}f(y',x')\ \mathrm{d}x'\ \mathrm{d}y'$$

Using the symmetry and reversing the condition $x'\ge y'$ we get halfway there:
$$\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x=\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D,y\le x}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x+\int_{y'\in D}\int_{x'\in D,y'\le x'}f(x',y')\ \mathrm{d}x'\ \mathrm{d}y'$$

However, the order of integration is still strong and I do not know how to fix this. What am I missing?

Comment: You need $f$ to be sufficiently nice to apply Fubini-Tonelli here.  Without some more details on $f$, I don't believe this is true.

Comment: Hmm. Let's assume that Fubini-Tonelli can be applied to $f$, how would the proof look like? (I was looking up the theorem, but could not find any connection to the $y\le x$ part.)

Comment: The missing step to applying Fubini-Tonelli directly is to define a second function $$\chi(x,y) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if } y\leq x \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Then $$\int_{y \in D}\int_{x\in D, y\leq x} f(x,y) \, dx\, dy = \int_{y \in D}\int_{x\in D} f(x,y)\chi(x,y) \, dx\, dy$$ Can you see how it would work from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking my attempt so far and the hints I got in the comments, the proof goes as follows:

**Proof**

1. Expand the integral.
   $$\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x=\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D,y\le x}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x+\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D,y\ge x}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x$$
2. Rename $x\rightarrow y'$ and $y\rightarrow x'$ in the second integral.
   $$\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x=\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D,y\le x}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x+\int_{y'\in D}\int_{x'\in D,x'\ge y'}f(y',x')\ \mathrm{d}x'\ \mathrm{d}y'$$
3. Use the symmetry $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$) and reverse the condition $x'\ge y'$.
   $$\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x=\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D,y\le x}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x+\int_{y'\in D}\int_{x'\in D,y'\le x'}f(x',y')\ \mathrm{d}x'\ \mathrm{d}y'$$
4. Replace the boundary conditions with the step function $\chi(x,y)$.
   $$\chi(x,y)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if}\ y\le x\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
   $$\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x=\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\chi(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x+\int_{y'\in D}\int_{x'\in D}f(x',y')\chi(x',y')\ \mathrm{d}x'\ \mathrm{d}y'$$
5. Apply [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).
   $$\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x=\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\chi(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x+\int_{x'\in D}\int_{y'\in D}f(x',y')\chi(x',y')\ \mathrm{d}y'\ \mathrm{d}x'$$
6. Simplify.
   $$\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x=2\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\chi(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x$$
7. Put $\chi(x,y)$ back as a boundary condition.
   $$\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x=2\int_{x\in D}\int_{y\in D,y\le x}f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x\ \blacksquare$$

**Note**

Step 5. applies [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), and thus implicitly implies:
$$\int_{D\times D}|f(x,y)\chi(x,y)|\ \mathrm{d}(x,y)<+\infty\text{,}$$
which in turn implies:
$$\int_{D\times D}|f(x,y)|\ \mathrm{d}(x,y)<+\infty\text{.}$$